# rxjava2 with spring boot 2

Tags: rx-java2, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using rxjava 2 with spring boot 2 and spring cloud finchley.rc2.

Now i am tracing the requests with sleuth / zipkin. But i am getting one issue that IO threads are reusing the olds requests traceids.

When I am doing this, traceids generated are fine(same for all parallel calls in same request )

```
Observable<Optional<String>> data = client.getWorld().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
        Observable<Optional<String>> data1 = client.getWorld1().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
        Observable<Optional<String>> data2 = client.getWorld1().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
        Observable<Optional<String>> data3 = client.getWorld().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
```

But when I am doing this, it is not working properly.
I am assuming since io() threads are reused, thats why they are using old data since they are old threads? But how can i force them to use the trace id for current main thread?

```
    Observable<Optional<String>> data = client.getWorld().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    Observable<Optional<String>> data1 = client.getWorld1().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    Observable<Optional<String>> data2 = client.getWorld1().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    Observable<Optional<String>> data3 = client.getWorld().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

How can i fix this? I cant move the webflux as i have lot of code writtenin rxjava?

Comment: Hey, just checking. Could you get the tracking to work with rxjava ?

Comment: Moved to mono/flux, reactive framework inbuilt with spring boot 2. Very less effort needed. Exactly same syntax / concepts